# Auto detect and auto pan to ball in video

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation, tracking

I'd like to set up a 4K video camera in the corner of a soccer field and just let it record. Afterwards I'd like to use a video editor to zoom into a smaller (1080) area where the ball is and auto pan to follow.

This takes too long to do manually. Do you know any software that will track the ball (or movement of people) and zoom into that area generating a 1080 or 720 output of the action around the ball? If not automatically, any suggestions on the fastest/easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in real life by attaching a transmitter to the ball and having a robotic pan/tilt tripod head track the movement.  If you're shooting 4K, your budget's probably in line with something like [soloshot](http://shop.soloshot.com). Or, of course, you could pay a cam-op.  Taking the time (or paying someone) to track it in Mocha or AE will end up being more expensive than capturing the moment as it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can track movements of the ball (if it is not covered with something) with After Effects, or better with Mocha. After that just zoom and lock the center of your video tho the ball. However your video will be really shaky. Ball will do lot of little moments, so you need to smooth your video shake.